# How to control what gets imported when you unpickle python object?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I have the following setup:

`a.py`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def a(self):
        print('yow {}!'.format(self.name))
```

`b.py`:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
```

`sender.py`:

```
from a import A
from b import B
message = pickle.dumps(B(A('Martin')))
```

`receiver.py`:

```
my_b = pickle.loads(message)
my_a = my_b.obj
my_a.a()
```

Output: `yow Martin!`

In `sender.py` I pickle the object `b` which acts as a carrier for the object `a`. Then I send that pickled object `b` via RabbitMQ to **another process**. In `receiver.py` (which is another process) I get a message via RabbitMQ, unpickle object `b` and by magic `B` and `A` get imported automatically. Can I control what gets imported? I would like for worker `receiver.py` to consume as little memory as possible. But if modules get imported without my control it can get bloated very quickly.

Could someone explain how pickle imports stuff and what to do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of control is required? As you can see from the source, when you are running `pickle.loads(content)` it actually does:

```
def loads(str):
    file = StringIO(str)
    return Unpickler(file).load()
```

Then there is some magic. It reads a string as a file and dispatches its' content is based on specific keys:

```
GLOBAL          = 'c'   # push self.find_class(modname, name); 2 string args
INST            = 'i'   # build & push class instance
```

Loading function itself:

```
def load(self):
    """Read a pickled object representation from the open file.
    Return the reconstituted object hierarchy specified in the file.
    """
    ...
    read = self.read  # self.read = file.read, which is StringIO's read()
    dispatch = self.dispatch
    try:
        while 1:
            key = read(1)
            dispatch[key](self) # this function call makes a future import.
   except _Stop, stopinst:
       return stopinst.value
```

You are intrested in method `find_class()`, which is used in several other `load functions` (`load_inst()` and `load_global()`):

```
def find_class(self, module, name):
    # Subclasses may override this:
    __import__(module)  # straight-forward import, you can ovveride it.
    mod = sys.modules[module]
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
    return klass
```

For example, `load_inst()` function:

```
def load_inst(self):
    module = self.readline()[:-1]
    name = self.readline()[:-1]
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
    # Now module is imported and ready to be used:
    self._instantiate(klass, self.marker())
dispatch[INST] = load_inst
```

So, if you want to control namespaces or modules, which can be imported, you will need to subclass `Unpickler` and override `find_class()` to fit your goals. Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 2):

It uses the `__module__` attribute of `A` and `B`:

```
>>> A.__module__
'a'
>>> __import__(A.__module__)
<module 'a' from 'a.py'>
```

If you want to control what is imported, you can structure your python packages so that `from a import A` doesn't load too many objects.

Answer (score 1):

`pickle` needs to import the modules `a` and `b` in order to load the classes `A` and `B`, which are needed to re-build your object. I took your example and just renamed a.py to aaaa.py and b.py to bbbb.py. Now, if we print the message (the pickled object) that sender.py is actually sending, you see this:

```
ccopy_reg
_reconstructor
p0
(cbbbb
B
p1
c__builtin__
object
p2
Ntp3
Rp4
(dp5
S'obj'
p6
g0
(caaaa
A
p7
g2
Ntp8
Rp9
(dp10
S'name'
p11
S'Martin'
p12
sbsb.
```

You don't need to make sense of all of it, but notice that `bbbb` followed by `B`, and `aaaa` followed by `A` are in there. That's there to tell `pickle` how to rebuild your pickled object. In order to load the classes, it has to import the modules the the classes are defined in. If you were to try to mess with pickle's machinery and block the modules from being loaded, there would be no way to rebuild your object.