# How to port feature pipeline from scikit-learn V0.21 to V0.24

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to port a sklearn feature pipeline trained in scikit-learn V0.21 to scikit-learn V0.24, because I do not have the original feature data to train the pipeline again. If I use new data, the feature dimension and position may be off from the following model, as I have DictVectorizer in the pipeline.

I've tried to use **pickle** and **joblib** to serialize the pipeline in V0.21 and then deserialize it in V0.24. Unfortunately, in both cases, the code raised `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.feature_extraction.dict_vectorizer'` error when loading in V0.24.

I created the pipeline with the same code using V0.21 and V0.24 respectively. When printing them out, they show some minor difference.

In V0.21

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('selector', ItemSelector(key='hsd_feature_map')),
                ('dv1',
                 DictVectorizer(dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, separator='=',
                                sort=True, sparse=False)),
                ('tfidf',
                 TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=True,
                                  use_idf=True)),
                ('max', MaxAbsScaler(copy=True))],
         verbose=False)
```

In V0.24

```
Pipeline(steps=[('selector', ItemSelector(key='hsd_feature_map')),
                ('dv1', DictVectorizer(sparse=False)),
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True)),
                ('max', MaxAbsScaler())])
```

I wonder if there is anyway to transfer the feature pipeline or its parameters from scikit-learn V0.21 to V0.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sklearn version [0.22.X](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.22.X/sklearn/feature_extraction/_dict_vectorizer.py) `DictVectorizer` import changed
from

```
sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py
```

to

```
sklearn/feature_extraction/_dict_vectorizer.py
```

I think you could override the `DictVectorizer` import according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396582/12483346)

Comment: Thank you very much, Miguel! Great insight!